# Should DbSets of nested classes be defined in DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Consider the following code:

```
public class MainObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    List<NestedObject> NestedObjects { get; set; }
}

public class NestedObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<MainObject> MainObjects { get; set; }

    // Should it be here? Code works without it...
    // DbSet<NestedObject> NestedObjects { get; set; }
}

// ( ... )

var nestedFooObjects = exampleContext.Get<NestedObject>()
      .Where(obj => obj.Name == "foo").ToList(); // still works
```

I was under the impression that a DBContext should contain all tables that are directly accessed from code. So without DbSet< NestedObject > it should only be possible to get MainObjects and then look for NestedObjects within the main ones. That is not the case apparently, as my experiments show. I want to get NestedObjects directly as in the example above. In that case: Should DbSet< NestedObject > be defined at all? Its not necessary for the code to run...

Comment: Can you please share your EF initialization/configuration code where you have mapped the entity classes to DB tables?

Comment: I am not really sure I understand your question. I use code-first approach, so the classes and the DBContext is pretty much all I have.